# Searching a string array in an association fails with Ransack

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ransack

I think I may know the answer already but I was hoping that there may be alternate solution.

I have a `User` model with `has_many` association to another model `Enrollment` with a string array `roles`.

I am trying to run a Ransack search on the roles for example:

```
:enrollments_roles_cont 'guest'
```

No matter which operator I use the search fails:

**CONT:**

```
PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  operator does not exist: text[] ~~* unknown
LINE 1: ..." IS NULL AND ("enrollments_public_users"."roles" ILIKE '%ma...
                                                             ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

**EQ:**

```
PG::InvalidTextRepresentation: ERROR:  malformed array literal: "manager"
LINE 1: ... IS NULL AND "enrollments_public_users"."roles" = 'manager' ...
                                                             ^
DETAIL:  Array value must start with "{" or dimension information.
```

I am guessing this fails because my 'array' column is actually a string.  So two questions.

1. Would switching that to an array type fix this?
2. Can I fix this another way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not pretty but it works:

In my `Enrollments` model:

```
ransacker :roles do
  Arel.sql("array_to_string(roles, ',')")
end
```

Comment: I'm trying to use this approach as well but not successful so far. Not sure where I'm going wrong, any chance you can take a look? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75370801/search-an-array-of-tags-with-ransack-on-associated-table?noredirect=1#comment133660325_75370801