# Search an array of tags with Ransack on associated table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, filter, ransack

I want to return a list of parks that have multiple tags applied. For example, users should be able to find a park that has all 3 tags:

1. Camping
2. Shade
3. BBQ

I've implemented a form where the user can select multiple tags using Ransack `_in` predicate, but it returns parks with ANY of the tags, rather than ALL of the tags. The `_in_all` predicate doesn't return any results when more than one tag is selected.

I found what looks like a promising approach in two different threads, but haven't succeeded in getting it to work in my code:

[Searching a string array in an association fails with Ransack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33968197/searching-a-string-array-in-an-association-fails-with-ransack) - Their solution:

```
ransacker :roles do
  Arel.sql("array_to_string(roles, ',')")
end
```

[Search an array of values with Ransack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49370841/search-an-array-of-values-with-ransack) - Their solution:

```
ransacker :rep_code_list do
  Arel.sql("array_to_string(rep_code_list, ',')")
end
```

In the console I can return the array I want with `parks.tags.ids`. So I thought I could somehow convert that array into a string and use Ransack's `cont` predicate to search. Here's my attempted solution but getting this error: `ActionView::Template::Error (PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "tags_ids" does not exist LINE 1: ... =  INNER JOIN "tagifications" ON "tagifications"."park_id" = "parks"."id" INNER JOIN "tags" ON "tags"."id" = "tagifications"."tag_id" WHERE array_to_string(tags_ids, ',') ILIKE '%["21"]%'`

What am I doing wrong?

models/park.rb

```
class Park < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :tagifications, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :tags, through: :tagifications

  ransacker :tags_ids do
    Arel.sql("array_to_string(tags_ids, ',')")
  end
end
```

controllers/parks_controller.rb

```
class ParksController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @parks = @q.result(distinct: true).joins(:visited_users, :favorited_users, :tags).near(@user_coordinates, 100000000).paginate(page:params[:page], :per_page => 24)
    @tags = Tag.all
  end

end
```

views/parks/index.html.erb

```
<% @tags&.each do |tag| %>
  <%= f.check_box :tags_ids_cont, { multiple: true, include_hidden: false, class: "btn-check", onchange: 'this.form.submit();', id: tag.name.titleize+"Checkbox" }, tag.id %>
  <%= f.label :tags_ids, tag.name.titleize, class: 'btn btn-outline-secondary border mb-1', for: tag.name.titleize+"Checkbox" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I don't really know Ransack that well but in plain ActiveRecord you would do `Park.joins(:tags).group(:id).where(tags: { id: tag_ids }).having(Tag.arel_table[:id].count.gte(tag_ids.length))`.

Comment: Joining the table will give you all rows with at least one match - but applying the group and using having limits it to parks that at least have all the tags in the list. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36131803/sql-where-joined-set-must-contain-all-values-but-may-contain-more

Comment: Thanks @max I will try to figure out how to use this approach. Where in the code would you put this? In the Park model (trying to go based on the thread you linked with sports and offers)?

`class Park < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :tagifications, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :tags, through: :tagifications

  def self.includes_tags(*tag_ids)
 joins(:tags).group(:id).where(tags: { id: tag_ids }).having(Tag.arel_table[:id].count.gte(tag_ids.length))
  end
end`

Comment: A class method seems like the right place but I can't really help you with integrating it with ransack.